# How can I decode this encrypted JavaScript code?

Tags: javascript, encoding

I'm trying to customize a blogger template that I downloaded the other day, but there is some JavaScript code that I cannot decode, something like this:

```
window[_0xdf0c[174]] = function () {
var _0xbaafx39 = document[_0xdf0c[176]](_0xdf0c[175]);
if (_0xbaafx39 == null) {
    window[_0xdf0c[177]][_0xdf0c[42]] = _0xdf0c[178]
};
_0xbaafx39[_0xdf0c[179]](_0xdf0c[42], _0xdf0c[178]);
_0xbaafx39[_0xdf0c[179]](_0xdf0c[109], _0xdf0c[180]);
_0xbaafx39[_0xdf0c[179]](_0xdf0c[112], _0xdf0c[181]);
_0xbaafx39[_0xdf0c[179]](_0xdf0c[182], _0xdf0c[183]);
_0xbaafx39[_0xdf0c[184]] = _0xdf0c[185]
}
```

First I thought it was hexadecimal encoded, so I tried [ddecode.com/hexdecoder](http://ddecode.com/hexdecoder/) and many other online tools, but nothing sames to work.

Does anyone have an idea how this snippet of code is encoded and how can I decode it? Thanks

You can download the full code [here](https://sites.google.com/site/allbloggerscripts/test.js)

Comment: Those are variables.  You need to check what their values are.

Comment: Decoding and decrypting are two entirely different things. It's not base64 encoded. Do you have any idea what the original encoding is?

Comment: I couldn't include the original code because it's to large, but basically it's implemented as the same code above

Comment: It's possible it was generated from a code obfuscator.

Comment: The variables aren't encrypted as much as obfuscated. I doubt there's a way to go backwards because this was probably done using some sort of automatic tool that would discard the original variables altogether. Looking at this code I'd say that somewhere there is an array of strings (also probably encoded like this) called _0xdf0c with at least 185 entries (probably a map of all the strings in the code). There's also an object called _0xbaafx39 which my guess would be that it holds all the functions and/or other objects the code uses. Does the code expose these variables?

Comment: I have encountered code like this before and I may be able to help you but you need to post the full code.

Comment: I added a download link for the full code in the post above. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

1. Open This [Website](http://ddecode.com/hexdecoder/)
2. Paste Your Code
3. Click Decode Button

Comment: OP said he used exactly that website and it did not work.